# How to get value of second span value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to write a very simple python script with **beautifulsoup**

```
import smtplib
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import sched, time

s = sched.scheduler(time.time,time.sleep)

my_url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/USDTRY=X/'

uClient = uReq(my_url)

page_html = uClient.read()

uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")

#Div class where dollar and percentage
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)"})


#Variables
USDTORTY = containers[0].div.span.string
USDTORTYPERCENTAGE = containers[0].div.span[1].string
 

#General purpose event schedular

def exchange(sc):
    for container in containers:
        print("TRY TO USD: "+ USDTORTY, "PERCANTAGE: " +  USDTORTYPERCENTAGE)
        s.enter(1,1,exchange,(sc,))
s.enter(1,1,exchange,(s,))
s.run()
```

but in code bellow, I can't get second span value I get an error saying that 'line 1321, in **getitem**
return self.attrs[key]KeyError: 1'

```
USDTORTYPERCENTAGE = containers[0].div.span[1].string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for the working code and problem description.
according to documentation (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

> Using a tag name as an attribute will give you only the first tag by
> that name. If you need to get all the  tags, or anything more
> complicated than the first tag with a certain name, you’ll need to use
> one of the methods described in Searching the tree, such as find_all()

so you could try to replace

```
USDTORTY = containers[0].div.span.string
USDTORTYPERCENTAGE = containers[0].div.span[1].string
```

by

```
USDTORTY = containers[0].find_all('span')[0].string
USDTORTYPERCENTAGE = containers[0].find_all('span')[1].string
```